# Is there a way to determine whether an argument was specified in the command line while setting a meaningful default value?

Tags: python, argparse

say I have this:

```
parser.add_argument('--num_nodes', type=int, default=3)
```

After parsing the command-line, in case `args.num_nodes` is 3, I want to know if it got that value because the user specified `--num_nodes 3` in the command-line, or because the flag wasn't specified at all.

Is there a way to do that?

(I'm aware of the approach based on a "special" default value (e.g. -1, or `None`), and changing to the real default value (e.g. 3) in the code if the special value is detected. I prefer to avoid this approach, so the *real* default value is not hidden in the internals.)

Comment: Your approach is the common solution and it's fine, why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: because it hides the "real" default value somewhere inside the code, instead of where the argument is defined

Comment: you can't have it both ways

Comment: Theoretically, it could, if the parser would set a flag when an argument is explicitly passed.

Comment: @Ikke any idea if the parser does it? (or how to make it do it?)

Comment: @Itamar I'm not really sure, but creating a custom action seems promissing (https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#action-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally `parse_args` tracks this information in a variable, `seen_actions`.  It's a `set` of the actions that have been seen.  It uses this to test for required arguments.  You can see this action near the end of the `parser._parse_known_args` method (in the `argparse.py` file).  But this is a private method and variable, and thus not directly accessible to the user.

http://bugs.python.org/issue11588 explores providing a hook that would have access to this variable.  It could be used to test for the occurrence of all kinds of combinations of arguments.

Some ways around this:

- modify your own copy of `argparse.py` to access `seen_actions`.
- search `sys.argv[1:]` for the relevant argument flag(s).  It won't handle abbreviations and the various ways in which `-f` could occur, but otherwise it is a simple approach.
- temporarily set that argument to `required` and capture a `missing option` error.  I could elaborate on that if you want.
- fiddle with the defaults as you suggest.
- as Ikke suggests, a custom action which sets an occurrence flag.  If the action is not see, the flag won't be set.  This flag could be in the namespace, or in a global variable.

(p.s. positionals with nargs='*' or '?' require some special handling when it comes to testing whether they are 'seen' or not).

Comment: good tips. don't think I want to mess with argparse internals, or parse `sys.argv` on my own. I'll probably go with catching missing-option, or implementing a custom action. thanks.